# Query where has_one association is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Information model:

```
class Information < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

And the user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :information, optional: true
end
```

What is the idiomatic way to query where the User is nil on the Information?

I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
Information.where(user: nil)

=> []
```

In my dev database, I was expecting that to return 1 record because I had one set up in a fashion where the user is nil. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Information.includes(:user).where(users: {information_id: nil})

Answer (score 0):

You could find it using its foreign key:

```
Information.where(user_id: nil)
```

If you haven't set the foreign key yet, you can create a migration in this fashion:

```
  def change
    add_reference :informations, :users, index: true
  end
```

PD: I feel the relation there should be of the information having belongs_to user and the user having "has_one" information. Each user has one record of "information" right?.

Answer (score 0):

> Information.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(information_id) FROM
> users)')